# autoload.php Failed to open stream: No such file or directory with docker install

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, composer-php

The exact error I am getting is

Warning: require(/var/www/html/public/../vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/public/index.php on line 34

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/html/public/index.php:34 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/public/index.php on line 34

I have my laravel project inside a ./src directory with my docker files in the root

I understand the problem is with the dependencies I am supposed to get from the composer install but not really sure as I am using a composer image in my docker-compose.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "4306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel

  composer:
    image: composer:latest
    container_name: composer
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - laravel


  npm:
    image: node:13.7
    container_name: npm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['npm']

  artisan:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: artisan
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['php', '/var/www/html/artisan']
    networks:
      - laravel
```

And here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

I am a bit new to docker and not really sure how to begin debugging this.

Comment: Did you run `composer install` and `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: @aynber is this something I should do on my local machine or within docker? A big reason I am trying to set this up with Docker is so developers won't have to do it locally

Comment: Probably within Docker, but I'm not all that familiar with it. It does sound like the vendor folder doesn't exist within the laravel installation yet because composer has not been run

Comment: Hi @nikulasoskarsson I know this is old but did you manage to get this resolved? I'm getting a bit desperate with the same issue.